# (The/-) measles virus

Tags: articles, definite-articles

I have some doubts when it comes to describing viruses causing infectious diseases. I have consulted a couple of very well-written medical reference books, where the authors consistently drop the definite article in the names of viruses, so that the text reads: "The virus is most widespread in Europe. Measles virus is transmitted by..."

What are the reasons for omitting the article in this case? The way I understand it, we should talk about “the measles virus”, as we are distinguishing it from other types of viruses.

I’ll be most grateful for every hint.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about usage in a particular technical field.

Comment: Having checked the on-topic list (http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), how exactly is the question about grammar or word usage in a particular context off-topic?

Comment: Because it is about usage in a particular technical field and not about the general usage of the English language. More specifically, it is about a pattern of usage that appears to exist only in medical reference books. The only people who can really answer whether that usage is appropriate are *medical experts*; not experts on the English language. FWIW, "off-topic" here merely means "we aren't the right people to ask." Also, my comment is just opinion. Others may disagree. It takes a few others agreeing before anything happens.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I do agree that this kind of usage seems to be typical of medical reference books; however, I have already discussed it with a couple of medical experts and none of them could make up their mind as to why the article should be dropped or left in place - hence I have decided to ask for a linguistic consultation.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the clarifications provided in the comments:

> I have already discussed it with a couple of medical experts and none of them could make up their mind as to why the article should be dropped or left in place - hence I have decided to ask for a linguistic consultation.

This does not seem to be an *intended* practice so the only answers we can provide are to offer guesses about why the author instinctively chose to phrase things this way.

My hunch is that it was due to the exclusion of the article when refer to "measles":

> 1) Measles is transmitted by...
>
> 2) The measles is transmitted by...

(1) is [vastly preferred](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=_START_+measles%2C_START_+the+measles&year_start=1800) over (2) which could explain why the usage remained even after adding "virus":

> 3) Measles virus is transmitted by...
>
> 4) The measles virus is transmitted by...

Comparing the [usage frequencies](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=measles+virus%2C%28measles+virus+-+the+measles+virus%29%2Cthe+measles+virus&year_start=1800) for (3) and (4) shows the former as "winning".

---

But as I said, this is just a guess. The NGram plots linked aren't a perfect answer to this question because it ignores the numbers from ["the * measles"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+%2a+measles&year_start=1800). This pattern, by the way, makes doing a similar comparison for "the flu" virtually impossible.

In the end, there is no specific grammatical reason to prefer one over the other. Whether to do so is a mixture of stylistic choice and what "sounds right".

---

To run the "ear test" on "the flu":

> 1) The flu is transmitted by...
>
> 2) Flu is transmitted by...

(2) sounds very wrong to me.

> 3) Flu virus is transmitted by...
>
> 4) The flu virus is transmitted by...

Likewise, I prefer (4).

(See above for an explanation of why I do not have tasty NGram plots for these.)

Comment: 2) sounds fine, in the UK. In this part of the world, people don't normally include *the*, before *flu*. It's not necessary.

Comment: @Tristanr: Good to know, thanks. Does (3) also sound fine to you? That may help confirm my suspicions.

Comment: MrHen, no, because it's about something in particular (the flu virus), while 2) is about flu in general.

Comment: Oh, interesting. I am AmE so I have no idea "flu in general" even means. How would a BrE ear consider what I wrote about measles?

Comment: MrHen, I'm not a doctor but, my first comment is also my impression of your measles examples. Of those, 1) and 4) seem correct.

Comment: Oh, crap, I just realized I messed up the numbering between examples. Well, too late now. :P

Comment: Don't worry, it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting.  This use looks ok, but I can't explain why grammatically.  I think it is fine because in this sense they implication is infection.  If the describe the actual virus, the definite article should be used. *The measles virus has a capsule.*. But, *measles manifests by fever and rash*.  Disclaimer: I recall nothing about measles.

Answer (score 0):

If you're grateful for any hint (and if that will excuse my guessing) my guess is that it's that Latin doesn't have an article. You could substitute the Latin name into the sentence:

> *Morbillivirus*  is transmitted by...

Measles is a proper name, a noun; not an adjective. We're not saying "The green virus is ..."